# Modifiable text into textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

I'm looking for something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/L7dWc/

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
var i = $('input'),
    v = i.val();

if ($(this).hasClass('search')) {
   $(this).text('search'); 
   $('p').remove();    
}
else {
   $(this).text('update');
   $('<p></p>', { text: v }).insertBefore(i);
}

$(this).toggleClass('search');
});
```

But if I click a button, the text will turn into a text box and then two buttons will be present: Submit and Cancel. If I click the Submit button, the text box's contents will be submitted via a form. If I click cancel, the text box and the 2 buttons disappear and it reverts back to the original text.

I want to use this to edit text much like YouTube's edit a comment system.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L7dWc/39/) is what you are looking for. You will need to add more controls and js handlers for your requirement

```
$('#cancel').on('click', function () {
    var i = $('#txt'),
        v = $('#hdn').val();
    $('p').remove();

    $('#search').text('update');
    $('<p></p>', {
        text: v
    }).insertBefore(i); 
    i.val(v);
    $('#hdn').val(v);
    $('#search').addClass('search');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made a few modifications. Basically, I'm not sure how to submit the variable v now as a post method of a form. Also, how can I make it if there are multiple texts, they each have their own unique edit / cancel that doesn't interfere with the other one? http://jsfiddle.net/D7fUy/

Comment: I've edited it further here: http://jsfiddle.net/CSek4/ Now all I really need is a way to have multiple texts with their own separate edits.